# Two different TypeConverters for the same type in Room

Tags: android, sqlite, type-conversion, android-room

When you have to store some custom types in Room, you should use can `TypeConverters`. As type converters would be in a separate class with `TypeConverter` annotation without any rule on the names of converter function, how would you create `TypeConverter`s for converting a custom type to so many different other types.

An example would be

- `Date` to `String`
- `Date` to `Integer`

One solution would be creating two different classes for each conversion. 
Is it the only way or is there any other way I can do this?